# Need assistance with Handlebarsjs, template not working/rendering

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, handlebars.js

Before testing Handlebarsjs for myself, I searched for some tutorial on YouTube and watched it. So basically I followed the example that was shown on the video, although for some reason mine's not working.

Below is the template script that is in my html file (also the container for the template).

```
<div id="recents">
   <div id="recents-template-container" class="grid-container">
                    
   </div>
</div>

<script id="recents-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each jobposts}}
        <div id="box-{{@key}}" class="recents-box flex-container">
            <div class="box-row">
                <span id="jobtitle">{{jobtitle}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="box-row">
                <span id="company">{{company}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="box-row">
                <span id="year">{{experience.year}}</span>
                <span id="months">{{experience.months}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="box-row">
                <span id="location">{{location}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>

<script type="module" src="src/js/index.js"></script>
```

Note: these two are at the end of the body tag.
And below is my index.js file

```
//index.js
import {recents} from "./query.js";
recents();
```

and query.js

```
//query.js
export function recents(){
const date = new Date();
const isoDate = `${date.getFullYear()}-0${(date.getMonth()+1)}-${date.getDate()}`;
const url = `http://localhost:3000/jobposts?dateposted_like=${isoDate}&_limit=5`;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);

            createRecents(data);
        }, 
        error: function(data){
            console.error(data);
        }
    });


    function createRecents(data){
        const template = $("#recents-template").html();
        const compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(template);
        const html = compiledTemplate(data);
        
        $("#recents-template-container").html(html);
    }
});
}
```

I also tried the template on the website of Handlebarjs, and it wworks. Is there something wrong in how I implemented it or how I coded it?

P.S. Sorry if my code looks bad.

Comment: Seems to me that first of all createRecents function inside the recents function never gets executed.

Comment: It actually gets execeute I tried replacing this `$("#recents-template-container").html(html);`, with `$("#recents-template-container").html("Testing testing");` and it worked.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: @kmgt I get no errors at all, although when I tried to console.log() the compiledTemplate, it's blank.

Comment: You should check the existence of handlebrs `console.log(typeof Handlebars)`.